# imported variable update is not reflecting in the parent module

Tags: python, python-import, python-datamodel

i have two modules, main and update.

in main, i declare a dictionary of references and a list for each value. In update i update the age, but i do not see the update reflecting in the main module again.

```
main module

candidates = {'goutham': {'Age': 30}, 'teja':{'Age': 27}}

for s in candidates:
    portfolio[s] = [0,0] # some value which i use for other calculations

update module
from main import *

portfolio['goutham'][0] = 32
```

Now when i come back to main and print the portfolio['goutham']. It still shows the values as [0,0]

Comment: What data structure do you want to have? `candidates` is a dictionary of dictionaries and `portfolio` should have what as keys? Then, you assign `[0, 0]` to an entry in `portfolio`, but later you assign just a scalar `32`. Decide on your data structures first.
Your code might not be working, because keys to portfolio are `candidates` dictionary entries, whereas later you try to access `portfolio` by a simple string `goutham`.

Comment: Which script is the one you execute?

Comment: @Maciek - I have actually represented my issue in a small way. The actual purpose of my program is for algo trading, i have the list of stocks in something called trd_portfolio, which is a dictionary of dictionary containing details of any particular stock. Then i have certain dataframes like profit_calculation, ohlc, etc. But to arrive at these dataframes using the stock tick data i get, i created lists of each table with the individual values from the initial dictionary as keys. In Short, for every entry in the dict, there will be a list, upon certain condition, that list is added to Datafra

Comment: Well, in any case, just see my answer, which actually modifies the data (which was your original problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. this should work print  `{'goutham': [32, 0], 'teja': [0, 0]}` when you run `run.py` which I added:

main.py

```
candidates = {'goutham': {'Age': 30}, 'teja':{'Age': 27}}
portfolio = {candidate:[0, 0] for candidate in candidates.keys()}
```

update.py

```
from main import *
portfolio['goutham'][0] = 32
```

run.py

```
import update
from main import *
print(portfolio)
```

As a side comment: right now you have in your modules that is being executed when the module is imported. If it is your main logic, consider putting it in some `main()` function instead of relying on implicit execution on import.